# Remove all instances of duplicate cells (not entire rows / columns) in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
genes_1 = c("a","b","c","d","e")
genes_2 = c("f","g","c","e","j")
genes_3 = c("a","b","m","n","o")
df = data.frame(genes_1, genes_2, genes_3)
```

My desired output:

```
genes_1 = c("","","","d","")
genes_2 = c("f","g","","","j")
genes_3 = c("","","m","n","o")
df = data.frame(genes_1, genes_2, genes_3)
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: so, you want to blank-out any duplicated value across the entire data frame?

Answer (score 4):

0-dependency base R solution:

```
data.frame(
  genes_1 = c("a","b","c","d","e"),
  genes_2 = c("f","g","c","e","j"),
  genes_3 = c("a","b","m","n","o"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) -> xdf

dups <- names(which(table(unlist(xdf, use.names = FALSE)) > 1))

xdf[] <- lapply(xdf, function(x) { x[x %in% dups] <- "" ; x })

xdf
```

`unlist()` recursively unwinds all the columns into a single character vector.

`table()` counts all occurrences of each element.

`which()` narrows down to only the ones which are `TRUE`

`names()` grabs the character select vector elements.

We then work by column to replace all occurrences in the vector that match with `""`

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

microbenchmark(
  base = {
    ydf <- xdf
    dups <- names(which(table(unlist(ydf, use.names = FALSE)) > 1))
    ydf[] <- lapply(ydf, function(x) { x[x %in% dups] <- "" ; x })
  },
  base.2 = {
    ydf <- xdf
    tmp <- unlist(ydf)
    ydf[arrayInd(which(duplicated(tmp) | duplicated(tmp, fromLast = TRUE)), dim(ydf))] <- ""
  },
  tidyverse = {
    ydf <- xdf
    ydf %>%
      gather(genes, value) %>%
      add_count(value) %>%
      mutate(value = ifelse(n > 1, "", value)) %>%
      select(-n) %>%
      group_by(genes) %>%
      mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
      spread(genes, value) %>%
      select(-ID) -> ydf
  },
  data.table = {
    ydt <- data.table(xdf)
    ydt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) { x[x %in% dups] <- "" ; x })]
  }
) %>%
  { print(.) ; . } %>% 
  autoplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another base solution:

```
tmp <- unlist(df)
df[arrayInd(which(duplicated(tmp) | duplicated(tmp,fromLast=TRUE)), dim(df))] <- NA

#  genes_1 genes_2 genes_3
#1    <NA>       f    <NA>
#2    <NA>       g    <NA>
#3    <NA>    <NA>       m
#4       d    <NA>       n
#5    <NA>       j       o
```

`unlist` just creates a long vector for all the values in `df`
`arrayInd` then creates a two-column row/column index for subsetting `df` for the `duplicated` values.

Comment: Good answer. The OP asks `""` not `NA` though. So the OP probably needs to convert all columns to character. After that, he or she can replace the duplicates with `""`

Comment: Aye. Def  (and nudges mine out of 1st place speed-wise)

Comment: @hrbrmstr - cheers - I think yours is by far the winner on a bigger dataset though. Having to save `tmp` or run `unlist` twice knocks my timing way up.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the case, but it's a super elegant approach. I esp like how the use of `duplicated()` really makes the operation very explicit/readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. `df2` is the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  gather(genes, value) %>%
  add_count(value) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(n > 1, "", value)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  group_by(genes) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(genes, value) %>%
  select(-ID)
```